# Rails has_many association allow to only add new relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to allow someone to select from a list of options (from a related model). The list is pretty simple:

```
= f.association :selected_companies, as: :check_boxes, collection: Company.order(:name)
```

After setting up the model in a correct way, I'm now able to select and deselect companies from the list.

Now I'm trying to improve this, so that the user is only able to select new companies, but not remove already selected ones. Is there an easy way to achieve this in Rails?

So to clarify:

1. User can select one or more options
2. User saves the form (new records are created for each of the selected options)
3. User goes back to page, is unable to deselect the already selected records, but can check additional ones and hit save again.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve here? That the user in the form can't uncheck the checkboxes? 
Because if you submit the form, you can just chose what to do with the values and just add the extra elected companies.

Comment: Yes correct, but ideally I'd have my view automatically render the checkboxes as deactivated (if they are persisted)

Comment: See also my clarificiation in the post... I'm wondering what is needed in my Model / Controller / View

Comment: So yeah, you need to specify in the view, that the checkboxes are deactivated. Mh. 
try `check_box_tag 'eula', 'accepted', false, disabled: true` you can find more explanation here:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

Comment: So I'm actually using the association... if I need to switch to chekbox helper, that would mean a lot of more overhead. Was actually hoping that there was some sort of setting in my Company model, or in the model responsible for saving the selected Company.

Comment: I understand, but I an't think of a solution like this... maybe if you have a scope on selected_companies? Just an idea

Comment: The checkbox helper is actually less overhead since its what SimpleForm uses under the covers. Verbosity and overhead are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The association [checkboxes and select helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease) in Rails work by using the `_ids=` setters and `_ids` getters [auto-generated by `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Collection+associations+-28one-to-many+-2F+many-to-many-29). SimpleForm just wraps these with a bit of convenience and flair.

The `_ids=` setter takes an array and will automatically add or delete rows in the join table.

```
@user = User.create!(name: "Bob", selected_company_ids: [1,2,3])
# This removes the assocation with 3 and adds an association to 4
@user.update!(selected_company_ids: [1,2,4])
```

If you want to allow the user to only add to the association you would need to merge the input with the existing ids:

```
ids = (@user.selected_company_ids + [1,2,4]).uniq
@user.update!(selected_company_ids: ids)
@user.selected_company_ids == [1,2,3,4] # true
```

In a controller you could do this by:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def update
     @user = User.eager_load(:selected_companies).find(params[:id])
     ids = (user_params[:selected_company_ids].map(&:to_i) + @user.selected_company_ids).uniq
     if @user.update(user_params.merge(selected_company_ids: ids))
       redirect_to @user
     else
       render :edit
     end
  end

  # ...

  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(:name, selected_company_ids: [])
  end
end
```

To disable the existing inputs use the [`collection_check_boxes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) helper:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes(:selected_company_ids, Company.order(:name), :id, :name) do |b|
  = b.label
  = b.check_box(disabled: b.object.selected_company_ids.include?(b.value))
end
```

AFAIK SimpleForm does not take a block for customization of each rendered input and would require a more complex solution like creating your own form builder.

Comment: Cool, thanks for explaining the internals of how Rails deals with this. Could you give me a bit more information on how the block part works in the update? Is there some documentation on this? I have never seen it in action before. Thanks.

Comment: There really is not that much to it - new, create, update etc all take an optional block argument and yield the record. The block is called before the record is saved. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Actually from looking at the docs i realized that update does not take a block, so You will need to alter the attributes hash instead.